# Send all request to v1/index.php - htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm in the process of building an api and want to redirect all requests to v1/index.php

My folder structure is;

```
-htdocs
--v1
----index.php
```

This is my htaccess atm

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

I want all requests sent to `api.example.co.uk` to go to `v1/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all requests sent to `api.example.co.uk` to go to `v1/index.php`

You can have this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =api.example.co.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ v1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: How can I enable full CORS

Comment: Sorry that wasn't part of your question, you will need to Google it as I am not aware of how to do that in Apache.

Comment: Do I put the `htaccess` in `v1` or `root` folder

Comment: No not in `v1` but a level above which should be your site root

Comment: For that you will need to check Apache error.log. Also what happens when you enter `http://api.example.co.uk/va/index.php` in browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you point you domain to `/htdocs/v1/` folder and place inside with your `index.php` this `.htaccess` file it will redirect any request to `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```